# regex for detecting numbers typed as strings

Tags: regex

I have this regex to match numbers of length more than 3.

```
/[+0123456789]{3,}/
```

So, this detects

```
123, 896540, 4654654654
```

I want to do the same with numbers written in letters.

```
onetwothree, eightninesixfivefourzero, ...
```

Can somebody help me to find regex for this ?

Comment: Why the `+` in your character class? Your regex would match `+++`, that's probably not what you want, is it?

Comment: No, thats not I want, I just want to match 3 or more numbers, and also the ones with a plus prefixed. 

The final regex I have is this /\b(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|zero|[+0123456789]){3,}/

I did not see +++ getting matched in this 
http://regexr.com/3a10i

Comment: Careful, that regex will fail to match `+4412345` because `\b` only works around (alphanumeric)  words, not punctuation. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can use [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to denote single-character alternatives, you need to use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) if your alternatives are longer. Other than that, no change:

```
/\b(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|zero){3,}/
```

I've also added [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to make sure you don't accidentally match parts of words like `done` or `height`.

To combine both, use

```
/\+?\b(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|zero|[0-9]){3,}/
```

Comment: This will also match `one9two`, but the OP is probably fine with that.

Comment: @georg: Thanks for editing my answer - I wonder where those dashes came from. They weren't in my original answer, and they don't show up in the edit history...

Answer (score 4):

```
(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|zero){3,}
```

You can try this.

```
^[+-]?(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|zero){3,}$
```

Add anchors to make it failproof.Also add `+` and `-` outside if you expect users to put it.